# JsonArray and Gson

Tags: json, gson, arrays

The JSON library I'm using is Gson. I'm having difficulty formulating a functioning data type to represent the following JSON string:

```
{  
   "latestoffers": [
      {
         "id": "4qXleunwNMCKi8M0q0CuMa",
         "price": "534.99",
         "firstrecorded_at": 1377808800,
         "lastrecorded_at": 1382862800,
         "seller": "Newegg",
         "availability": "In stock. [BBX: Buy Box]",
         "currency": "USD"
      },
      {
         "id": "4xTIQAPySG68IS0CGyOuyO",
         "price": "582.41",
         "firstrecorded_at": 1380725000,
         "lastrecorded_at": 1382862800,
         "seller": "Beach Audio",
         "currency": "USD"
      },
      {
         "id": "5nW67R2V4CwmE8cwaWsawe",
         "price": "578.04",
         "firstrecorded_at": 1379524200,
         "lastrecorded_at": 1379998900,
         "seller": "Beach Audio",
         "currency": "USD"
      }
      ],
   "offers_count": 6,
   "name": "newegg.com",
   "recentoffers_count": 2,
   "sku": "N82E16834216463",
   "url": "http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834216463"
}
```

My data class (so far) is as follows, it's the method ***getOfferData()*** that I don't how to complete. I'm also not certain whether JsonArray is the appropriate JSON element to be using?

```
static class LatestOffers {

    Integer offers_count;
    String name;
    Integer recentoffers_count;
    String sku;
    String url;

    java.util.List<JsonArray> getOfferData() {

        List<JsonArray> list = new ArrayList<JsonArray>();
        // how do I get parse the 'id', 'price', 'firstrecorded_at' etc. to add them to the ArrayList?
          return list;
    }

    Integer getOffers_count() {
        return offers_count;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    Integer getRecentoffers_count() {
        return recentoffers_count;
    }

    String getSku() {
        return sku;
    }

    String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Any assistance, please? Thank you.

**EDIT**

Turns out I was unnecessarily complicating things, this works as intended:

```
static class LatestOffers {
        List<Offer> latestoffers;

        List<Offer> getOffer() {
            return latestoffers;
        }
    }

    static class Offer {

        private String id;
        private String price;
        private long firstrecorded_at;
        private long lastrecorded_at;
        private String seller;
        private String availability;
        private String currency;

        String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        String getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        long getFirstrecorded_at() {
            return firstrecorded_at;
        }

        long getLastrecorded_at() {
            return lastrecorded_at;
        }

        String getSeller() {
            return seller;
        }

        String getAvailability() {
            return availability;
        }

        String getCurrency() {
            return currency;
        }

    }
```

Thank you to all who answered, I'm accepting the answer of user2762451 as (s)he was the first to suggest the use of another class for the Offer data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you to make new POJO for object in array.

```
class Offer {
    private String id;
    private String price;
    private long firstRecordedAt;
    private long lastRecordedAt;
    private String seller;
    private String availability;
    private String currency;
```

}

And your `LatestOffers` class can have a `List<Offer> offers;` and the method `getOfferData()` should return `List<Offer>`.

Basically, the following:

```
static class LatestOfferDetail {
    private int offersCount;
    private String name;
    private int recentOffersCount;
    private String sku;
    private String url;
    private List<Offer> latestOffers = new ArrayList<Offer>();

    //other getters and setters
    public List<Offer> getLatestOffers() {
        return latestOffers;
    }
}
```

Also, you seem to be following multiple naming conventions in the same piece of code and JSON. With JAVA, it's advisable to follow CamelCaseNaming. I've updated answer to reflect those.

Also, your getter method for `latestOffers` has a name different from convention. It's advisable to name it like `get{FieldName}`. I've updated answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for this, user2762451. I understand that so far, the issue for me is how to parse the JSON to get the id, price, firstRecordedAt, etc. - the point being that (unlike for sku, url, etc.) there is no key value I can use to retrieve the Offer?

Comment: @ClivevanHilten the `latestOffers` is a list, effectively an array and array elements in JSON won't have a 'key' as such. what do you exactly want to do when you say, "key value I can use to retrieve Offer"?

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve the arrays containing id, price, firstRecordedAt, etc. in order to add them to the list?

Comment: @ClivevanHilten glad that it works and glad to have helped! btw, I'm 'he' :)

Answer (score 0):

Create another POJO contain all parameter use in array like below :

```
public class MyOffer  
{  
  private String id;  
  private double price;  
  private long firstrecorded_at;  
  private long lastrecorded_at;  
  private String seller;  
  private String availability;  
  private String currency;  

  //your getter and setter methods here.
}
```

Include List of above pojo in your class `LatestOffers` :

```
List<MyOffer> latestoffers = new ArrayList<MyOffer>();
```

your class `LatestOffers` look like this

```
static class LatestOffers   
{
    Integer offers_count;
    String name;
    Integer recentoffers_count;
    String sku;
    String url;

    List<MyOffer> latestoffers = new ArrayList<MyOffer>();

    //getter and setter method
}
```

Main Class for Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LatestOffers lso = new LatestOffers();
    lso.setName("N82E16834216463");
    lso.setOffers_count(6);
    lso.setRecentoffers_count(2);
    lso.setSku("N82E16834216463");
    lso.setUrl("http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834216463");
    MyOffer offer = null;
    List<MyOffer> list = new ArrayList<MyOffer>();
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
        offer = new MyOffer();
        offer.setAvailability("In stock. [BBX: Buy Box]");
        offer.setCurrency("USD");
        offer.setFirstrecorded_at(1377808800);
        offer.setId("4qXleunwNMCKi8M0q0CuMa");
        offer.setLastrecorded_at(1382862800);
        offer.setPrice(534.99);
        offer.setSeller("Newegg");

        list.add(offer);
    }
    lso.setLatestoffers(list);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(lso);
    System.out.println(json);

}
```

**Output :**

```
{
  "offers_count": 6,
  "name": "N82E16834216463",
  "recentoffers_count": 2,
  "sku": "N82E16834216463",
  "url": "http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834216463",
  "latestoffers": [
    {
        "id": "4qXleunwNMCKi8M0q0CuMa",
        "price": 534.99,
        "firstrecorded_at": 1377808800,
        "lastrecorded_at": 1382862800,
        "seller": "Newegg",
        "availability": "In stock. [BBX: Buy Box]",
        "currency": "USD"
    },
    {
        "id": "4qXleunwNMCKi8M0q0CuMa",
        "price": 534.99,
        "firstrecorded_at": 1377808800,
        "lastrecorded_at": 1382862800,
        "seller": "Newegg",
        "availability": "In stock. [BBX: Buy Box]",
        "currency": "USD"
    }
  ]
}
```

no need to define `getOfferData()` method just create list of `MyOffer` class and set that list into `latestoffers` list define in your class `LatestOffers`. It will serialize your list into JsonArray when you convert your POJO into JSON String.

Comment: Thank you for this Yagnesh. Could you possibly update your answer to include code covering your point 'it will serialize your list into JsonArray when you convert your POJO into JSON String'? It's that bit that I'm struggling to understand.

Comment: It will convert your list into array inside JSON string.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the reply to my comment. If you have a moment, the code (or even pseudo-code) would be very helpful so I can understand :-)

Comment: Pls see my updated answer. I have created test method that add your data into list as well as `LatestOffers` class object, at the end i have converted my object into JSON using GSON api. Output is same as want you want. If you still need any help your are well come.

Comment: thank you very much for your help on this question. As indicated in my edit to my question, I'm accepting the answer of user2762451 as he was the first to suggest the use of another class for the Offer data.